# Module delivery/shipping prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop

I created a custom module delivery/carrier, but I need to pass the weight of products, the ZIP Code of delivery and the order value for the webservice. I am not succeeding in taking this information into my module.

The following piece of code I'm using, actually, I'm following this example.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+carrier+module

```
public function getOrderShippingCost($params, $shipping_cost)
{ // here I call my webservice }
```

I believe that this information is within `$params`, but do not know how to handle them or what they are.

Comment: Try to see the content of $params with the following: echo '<pre>'.print_r($params, true).'</pre>';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was pretty simple to fix, just use the following command.

$address = new Address ($params->id_address_delivery); 
$zip = $address->postcode;

I can pick up any object parameter $address above.